# How to expand columns into individual timesteps in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, time-series

I have a table of columns that represent a time series. The datatypes are not important, but anything after `timestep2` could potentially be `NULL`.

```
| id | timestep1 | timestep2 | timestep3 | timestep4 |
|----|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| a  | foo1      | bar1      | baz1      | qux1      |
| b  | foo2      | bar2      | baz2      | NULL      |
```

I am attempting to retrieve a view of the data more suitable for modeling. My modeling use-case requires that I break each time series (row) into rows representing their individual "states" at each step. That is:

```
| id | timestep1 | timestep2 | timestep3 | timestep4 |
|----|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| a  | foo1      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |
| a  | foo1      | bar1      | NULL      | NULL      |
| a  | foo1      | bar1      | baz1      | NULL      |
| a  | foo1      | bar1      | baz1      | qux1      |
| b  | foo2      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |
| b  | foo2      | bar2      | NULL      | NULL      |
| b  | foo2      | bar2      | baz2      | NULL      |
```

How can I accomplish this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION.`

```sql
select id, timestep1, timestep2, timestep3, timestep4
from my_table

union

select id, timestep1, timestep2, timestep3, null
from my_table

union

select id, timestep1, timestep2, null, null
from my_table

union

select id, timestep1, null, null, null
from my_table

order by 
    id, 
    timestep2 nulls first, 
    timestep3 nulls first, 
    timestep4 nulls first
```

There is a more compact solution, maybe more convenient when dealing with a greater number of timesteps:

```sql
select distinct
    id, 
    timestep1, 
    case when i > 1 then timestep2 end as timestep2, 
    case when i > 2 then timestep3 end as timestep3, 
    case when i > 3 then timestep4 end as timestep4 
from my_table
cross join generate_series(1, 4) as i
order by 
    id, 
    timestep2 nulls first, 
    timestep3 nulls first, 
    timestep4 nulls first
```

Test it in [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=42700e84a1cff00aece8b95264a1281b)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This will work, though I'm curious whether there's a way to do it that will allow for an arbitrary number of time steps? This may also produce duplicates of records that had nulls to begin with, though that would be simple to filter out.

Comment: The problem is that in the database world there is no *arbitrary number of columns*. The number of resulting columns has to be defined before a query is executed. (The answer corrected to remove duplicates).